# How to insert row_number with multiple insert

Tags: sql-server

I am doing multiple insert statements on a table. How can I insert row_number(or any way to insert a counter) that continues the last number from the last insert?

Thanks.

Comment: Use an `IDENTITY` column instead?

Comment: @Larnu Actually I run the multiple inserts daily. And I need to reset the counter everyday.

Comment: You could create a stored procedure with a counter. It will get reset every time it is run. The limitation is, however, that if you run it multiple times on the same day and want those numbers continuous, every run will have a counter starting from its initial value.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I thought was to use a temporary table with `IDENTITY` column for the multiple inserts then do one final insert in the real table.

Thanks, @Larnu for giving me an idea about using `IDENTITY`.